# session value not printing in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

Working on a laravel shopping cart. Added products with cart dump.

```
App\Cart {#319 ▼
  +items: array:1 [▼
    3 => array:3 [▼
      "quantity" => 1
      "totalsingleprice" => 130
      "date" => App\product {#328 ▶}
    ]
  ]
  +totalQuantity: 1
  +totalPrice: 130
}
```

With the dump i am printing the total quantity in laravel header to display in all view pages as below.

```
@if(Session::has('cart'))
   {‌{ Session::get('cart')->totalQuantity }}
   @endif
```

It is not showing the Total quantity instead showing  {‌{ Session::get('cart')->totalQuantity }}

Help me sort out issue

Comment: is your header a blade template? How is it included?

Comment: try `dd(Session::get('cart'))` - what it shows?

Comment: @krylov123 dd(Session::get('cart')) - prints the same dd(Session::get('cart')) not the value

Comment: @apokryfos - incuded as @include('header')

Comment: is `header` a blade template?

Comment: `<?php session('cart')->totalQuantity; ?>` try this one

Comment: @apokryfos - yes header is blade template

Answer (score 0):

Tried this &it worked

totalQuantity ; ?>